# Prove $B\vec{v_2}=\vec{v_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Let $B$ be a matrix $n$ by $n$ such as $(B-I)^2=0$.
> Let $\vec{v_1}$ be a vector $\mathbb{R}^n $ such as $B\vec{v_2}≠\vec{v_1}$.
> $\vec{v_2}$ is defined to be $B\vec{v_1}-\vec{v_1}$.
> Prove that $B\vec{v_2}=\vec{v_2}$

What I tried is shown in this picture, hopefully it's clear enough:

[image: my work]

But I'm struggling to continue so I was wondering if anyone could shine a light on this.

Comment: The question is very false: most vectors and most matrices will fail this. Did you mean $(B - I)^2 = 0$?

Comment: My bad, I do mean $(B-I)^2=0$, sorry. Will edit this

Comment: Note: $v_2 = (B - I)v_1$ and showing $Bv_2 = v_2$ is equivalent to showing $(B - I)v_2 = 0$, i.e. $(B - I)(B - I)v_1 = 0$, i.e. $(B - I)^2v_1 = 0$. So, as you can hopefully see, this condition of $Bv_2 = v_2$ is actually *equivalent* to saying $(B - I)^2v_1 = 0$ for all $0$, i.e. $(B - I)^2 = 0$. That's how I guessed that you meant $(B - I)^2 = 0$ instead of $(B - I)^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: One extra note about your attempt: be careful when "dividing" by matrices. Matrix division does not really exist; the best you can do is multiply by the inverse matrix. For general $n \times n$ matrices $A, B$, where $B$ is invertible, it's not clear whether $\frac{A}{B}$ denotes $AB^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}A$, since the two may not be the same! You also should be careful when "dividing" non-zero matrices, since being non-zero does not necessarily imply that it has an inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Pick

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\ \mathrm{and}\ v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, we have that

$$v_2=(B-I)v_1=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

and $Bv_2\ne v_2$.

Edit. This is true whenever $(B-I)^2=0$ since $$Bv_2=B(B-I)v_1=B^2v_1-Bv_1.$$ Now, we have that $(B-I)^2=0$ implies that $B^2-B=B-I$ and substituting that above yields

$$Bv_2=B(B-I)v_1=B^2v_1-Bv_1=(B-I)v_1=v_2.$$

Comment: My bad, I do mean $(B-I)^2=0$, sorry. Will edit this.